# Why is this Swift Playground Printing & Looping Twice?

Tags: swift, xcode8, swift-playground

I can't figure out why the `for` loop and *everything* I print are repeating.

I could have *sworn* they weren't doing this before I wrote the `for` loop, but I tried relaunching Xcode; copying the code into a new playground; commenting out the last few lines; and googling—-to no avail.

The fact that the `prints` are all executed once before apparently being executed a second time makes me think somehow the whole thing is being called twice, and maybe that would explain the loop too, but I just don't see how that could be happening.

I'm running Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b) (not a development version).

Here's the code, below is a screenshot of what I'm getting

```
//: I don't see why it's printing everything twice, or why the for loop is looping twice

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class CustomView: UIView {

    let pathCG: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x:50, y:300), CGPoint(x:100, y:350), CGPoint(x:230, y:350), CGPoint(x:230, y:120)]

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        print("what the hell")
        print(pathCG)
        print(pathCG.dropLast().count)

        for v in 0...pathCG.dropLast().count {
            let segAngle = vecDirCG(vec: [pathCG[v], pathCG[(v+1) % 4]]) * 180/CGFloat.pi
        }
    }

    // MARK: get direction given two points
    func vecDirCG(vec: [CGPoint]) -> CGFloat {
        return atan2(-vec[1].y + vec[0].y, vec[1].x - vec[0].x)
    }
}

let containerView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 600))
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
```

[image: printing & looping twice]

EDIT: here's an update after taking @MohammadSadiq's answer. It got rid of the double printing, but the double looping seemed to remain. However, changing the values of a `CGPoint` in `pathCG` would only change the *first* results of the loop, not the second. And now I noticed that commenting out the `container.backgroundColor` line in the original playground *has* fixed the (apparent) duplicate execution (of the loop), so I'm thinking it's some kind of caching issue.

[image]

Comment: because that is how `draw` calls work, you cannot be sure when and how often it is called, that is why you should not do any business logic inside the rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)`

> This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event
>   occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view.

Your line

```
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
```

might be causing draw to get another call.

Comment: Yeah, someone else had an answer (they deleted) saying to remove that line and put `self.backgroundColor = .orange` inside the function (I tried `... = UIColor.orange` too), and that did fix the double printing (though the `self...` part didn't seem to work), but it still seemed to execute the `for` loop twice.

Comment: I tested it. Its changing background that is causing the draw to get another call. Hence for loop printing it twice. That was your question and this is the answer. Can you please clarify what else you want  to ask?

Comment: @Cody, how have you confirmed that _it still seemed to execute the for loop twice_? There's no `print` inside the for loop.

Comment: draw() is getting called twice.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq, I am asking to Cody things after _that did fix the double printing_.

Comment: @OOPer, with the "show result" showing, I control-click the result and select "value history" and it shows the loop output twice in a row. It's the same way you can see the loop output in the picture I posted in the question. @MohmmadSadiq your answer did fix the double printing though, half the original question. I just found that changing one of the `CGPoint`s in `pathCG` causes a change in the *first* iteration of the loop, but not the second, so maybe a caching or something?

Comment: @Cody, do not rely on the Value History. It does not clear up the previous output well. By the way, what is the problem if your `draw(_:)` called twice?

Comment: It's not necessarily a problem, though I guess efficiency-wise it's a waste. Mostly it was the unexpected nature of it that was bothering me. This has all helped me understand some of these things a little bit better, along with the caveats. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Cody, Do you understand these `draw(_:)` call timings can be observed only in the Playground? In actual apps, `draw(_:)` is called at completely different timings.

Comment: I knew that what I was doing was pretty specific to the playgrounds, I was kinda prototyping drawing ideas, and working out types—my programming experience is pretty limited and it really helps to be able to peer into what's happening. In this case I just couldn't figure out why that was happening.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented by luk2302, in actual apps, it's hard to predict when or how many times `draw(_:)` is called. And the Playground is not a good place for exploring the behavior of `draw(_:)`.

In the Playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class CustomView: UIView {

    let pathCG: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x:50, y:300), CGPoint(x:100, y:350), CGPoint(x:230, y:350), CGPoint(x:230, y:120)]

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        print(pathCG)

        for v in pathCG.indices {
            let segAngle = vecDirCG(vec: [pathCG[v], pathCG[(v+1) % pathCG.count]]) * 180 / .pi
        }
    }

    // MARK: get direction given two points
    func vecDirCG(vec: [CGPoint]) -> CGFloat {
        return atan2(-vec[1].y + vec[0].y, vec[1].x - vec[0].x)
    }
}

let containerView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 600))
print("---------- CustomView created ----------")
containerView.backgroundColor = .orange
print("---------- backgroundColor set ----------")
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
print("---------- liveView set ----------")
```

The output:

> ```
> draw [(50.0, 300.0), (100.0, 350.0), (230.0, 350.0), (230.0, 120.0)]
> ---------- CustomView created ----------
> draw [(50.0, 300.0), (100.0, 350.0), (230.0, 350.0), (230.0, 120.0)]
> ---------- backgroundColor set ----------
> ---------- liveView set ----------
> ```

Seems `draw(_:)` is called twice,

- when creating a new instance of the View
- when modifying the `backgroundColor` property

But you should not think this behavior is the same as in actual apps.

---

In a Single View App:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let containerView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 600))
        print("---------- CustomView created ----------")
        containerView.backgroundColor = .orange
        print("---------- backgroundColor set ----------")
        self.view!.addSubview(containerView)
        print("---------- addSubview finished ----------")
    }

}

class CustomView: UIView {

    let pathCG: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x:50, y:300), CGPoint(x:100, y:350), CGPoint(x:230, y:350), CGPoint(x:230, y:120)]

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        print(#function, pathCG)

        for v in pathCG.indices {
            let segAngle = vecDirCG(vec: [pathCG[v], pathCG[(v+1) % pathCG.count]]) * 180 / .pi
        }
    }

    // MARK: get direction given two points
    func vecDirCG(vec: [CGPoint]) -> CGFloat {
        return atan2(-vec[1].y + vec[0].y, vec[1].x - vec[0].x)
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> ---------- CustomView created ----------
> ---------- backgroundColor set ----------
> ---------- addSubview finished ----------
> draw [(50.0, 300.0), (100.0, 350.0), (230.0, 350.0), (230.0, 120.0)]
> ```

`draw(_:)` is called only once after `addSubview` finished. (Actually, in the code above, it's called after `viewDidLoad` finished.)

---

The Playground keeps some intermediate results. For `UIView`s, it keeps the drawn results. (Which causes `draw(_:)` to be called.) But in actual apps, this sort of intermediate results are not kept, so `draw(_:)` may not be called at the same positions.